# Uploading RootCA to apim via az cli

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-api-management, azure-cli

Is there a function in the az cli which can perform the same operation via the Az Powershell module as documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/new-azapimanagementsystemcertificate?view=azps-5.8.0#related-links

I've reviewed the API docs and it seems like you can only update Certificate vs System Certificate: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2020-06-01-preview/certificate/createorupdate#apimanagementcreatecertificate

Essentially I want to automate the process of uploading a CA Certificate to API Management Service - was hoping to avoid having to install Powershell to perform this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such built-in equivalent for `New-AzApiManagementSystemCertificate` in Azure CLI, actually it is a wrapper to encode the certificate with base64 and integrate with the `certificatePassword`(can be omitted) and `storeName`, at last, it will get a `CertificateConfiguration`, then use `New-AzApiManagement` or `Set-AzApiManagement` to create/update the APIM, they essentially call the [`Api Management Service - Create Or Update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-12-01/apimanagementservice/createorupdate) RESt API.

So to do this in Azure CLI, you just need to use [`az rest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest#az_rest) to call the REST API directly.

First, use bash to base64 encode the certificate, in my test sample, it is a `.cer` certificate.

```
$ cat ./testapim.cer | base64 -w 0
```

[image]

Then pass it to the sample command below, modify the values with yours.

```
az rest --method put --uri https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<group-name>/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/joyapim?api-version=2019-12-01 --headers '{"Content-Type":"application/json"}' --body '{
  "properties": {
    "certificates": [
      {
        "encodedCertificate": "*******Base64 encoded Certificate******************",
        "certificatePassword": "Password",
        "storeName": "Root"
      }
    ],
    "publisherEmail": "xxxxx",
    "publisherName": "xxxxx"
  },
  "sku": {
    "name": "Developer",
    "capacity": 1
  },
  "location": "Central US"
}'
```

[image]

Check the result in the portal:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, and thank you to the reference to the API