# Azure APIM Management Certificate Automation/Renewal through Devops

Tags: azure-devops, certificate, azure-keyvault, azure-api-management, cicd

Currently, we are doing whole manual process of creating certificate in key vault, adding the  same certificate in APIM by selecting the key vault. But we would like to do automation through Azure DevOps using PowerShell or azure cli etc.,

So far we completed automation:
Automation of creation of certificate in key vault through Azure CLI commands in Azure Devops.

**Next Steps:**
Would like to automate choose this certificate that created in Key vault  while adding it to API Management.
Would like to automate certificate renewal in Azure Devops.

Appreciate if anyone can help me in this.

[image]

[image: azure-de]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to call the REST API "[**Api Management Service - Create Or Update**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/api-management-service/create-or-update?view=rest-apimanagement-2022-08-01&tabs=HTTP)" to add the certificate to Azure APIM service. When calling this API, you need convert the content of the certificate to be a Base64 string, and then pass the Base64 Encoded certificate to the request body of the API.

---

In pipeline, you can use an [**Azure CLI task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-cli-v2?view=azure-pipelines) to run the following commands to add the certificates from Azure Key Vault to Azure APIM service:

1. Run the "[**`az keyvault certificate download`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault/certificate?view=azure-cli-latest#az-keyvault-certificate-download)" command to download the certificate from Azure Key Vault. This command should have provided a parameter "[**`--encoding -e`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault/certificate?view=azure-cli-latest#az-keyvault-certificate-download-optional-parameters)" to create the downloaded certificate as a Base64 Encoded certificate.
2. Read and pass the content of the Base64 Encoded certificate to a variable (e.g., **`base64certificate`**) for use in the subsequent commands.
3. Use the "[**`az rest`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest#az-rest)" command to invoke a request of the REST API "**Api Management Service - Create Or Update**" and pass the Base64 Encoded certificate into the request body.

   ```bash
   . . .

   base64certificate='{content of Base64 Encoded certificate}'
   uri="https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/{serviceName}?api-version=2022-08-01"

   az rest -m put -u $uri \
   --headers '{"Content-Type":"application/json"}' \
   -b '{
     "properties": {
       "certificates": [
         {
           "encodedCertificate": "$base64certificate",
           "certificatePassword": "Password",
           "storeName": "Root"
         }
       ],
       "publisherEmail": "{publisherEmail}",
       "publisherName": "{publisherName}"
     },
     "sku": {
       "name": "{Name of the Sku}",
       "capacity": {Capacity of the SKU}
     },
     "location": "{Resource location}"
   }'
   ```

[There](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67232824/uploading-rootca-to-apim-via-az-cli) is a similar case that you also can reference.

---

Comment: @PavanKumarGVVS, Is there any update from you? Did you tried with the steps shared in my answer to add certificate from Azure Key Vault to Azure APIM service using Azure CLI in Azure pipeline?