# Export APIM Root CA certificates

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-api-management, azure-cli

We are currently migrating our Azure API Management instances inline with the [stv1 to stv2 migration](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/fasttrack-for-azure/migrating-api-management-platform-version-from-stv1-to-stv2/ba-p/3951108). I have created the new stv2 instance and used the [Backup/Restore functionality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-disaster-recovery-backup-restore?tabs=powershell) to copy over the existing stv1 configuration.

Problem is that it did not take the [root CA certificates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-ca-certificates) from the existing instance. I can see that the certificates are listed in the [APIM Get REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/api-management-service/get?view=rest-apimanagement-2022-08-01&tabs=HTTP#code-try-0) but I am not able to export from the Azure Portal or the Rest API.

Is there a mechanism to export the root CA certificates?

Comment: Have you tried any code so far? @Phil Murray

Comment: Azure Powershell and the RESTAPI based on the MS docs. From what I can see neither allows access to download certificates. If you can provide documentation link to a specific endpoint I would be happy to try it.

Comment: Can you check if this [functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67261562/19785512) works for you? @Phil Murray

Comment: Would need to download prior to upload. APIM Get Rest API lists the CA certificates but not export.